# Android Layout from downloaded xml

Tags: android, xml, layout, dynamic, sdk

I've got problem with my school project.
Basically user create a table on website with records and then by android app can upload own datas to table.
Table might have many rows with different type like integer, date, text. So in my app I need to create layouts dynamicly depends on defined table. I thought that I can convert rows to xml file and then create layouts in android, but it seems to be a difficult one. Can You suggest my how can I create that layouts from downloaded xml ? Or maybe is  the other simple way. Help

Comment: you need to dynamically add elements to your layout through code. Look through SO and you will find numerous examples

Comment: I forgot add that app's user can't create buttons or someting like that. He just choose table and upload data. The Problem is; how to create forms by application compatible with table record type. Table might have e.g. integer, text, date and another one only text.

Comment: So you will need validations according to the data you want to send. Can you give an example of what kind of xml are you getting from website.

Comment: I think you should send the schema of the table in json format to your app, then parse it in your app and create dynamic TextViews and Fields.